# R collapse multiple rows into 1 row using specific function to date & character columns

Tags: r, data.table

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

x1 <- c(20090101, "2009-01-02", "2009 01 03", "2009-1-4",
       "2009-1, 5", "Created on 2009 1 6", "200901 !!! 07")

dt2 <- data.table(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2), date1 = ymd(x1), charval = c("aa","vv","ss","a","b","c","d"))

   id      date1 charval
1:  1 2009-01-01      aa
2:  1 2009-01-02      vv
3:  1 2009-01-03      ss
4:  2 2009-01-04       a
5:  2 2009-01-05       b
6:  2 2009-01-06       c
7:  2 2009-01-07       d
```

I use next code for grouping by id:

```
dt3 <- dt2[, Map(function(x,y) ifelse(x != "paste", get(x)(y, na.rm = TRUE), paste(y, sep = ";")), 
                              setNames(c("mean", "paste"), names(.SD)), .SD), by = id]
```

to get something like this:

```
   id      date1 charval
1:  1 2009-01-02      aa;vv;ss
2:  2 2009-01-05      a;b;c;d
```

but in real I see next result:

```
   id date1 charval
1:  1    NA      aa
2:  2    NA       a
```

1) I dont understand why paste doesnt work
2) I dont understand why mean(date1) doesnt work 
because for example next code works fine:

```
mean(dt2$date1)
[1] "2009-01-04"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear why we have to go through `Map` and `get`.  After grouping by 'id', get the `mean` of 'date1' and `paste` the 'charval' together

```
dt2[, .(date1 = mean(date1), charval = toString(charval)), id]
#    id      date1    charval
#1:  1 2009-01-02 aa, vv, ss
#2:  2 2009-01-05 a, b, c, d
```

Note: `toString` is `paste(..., collapse=', ')`

```
dt2[, .(date1 = mean(date1), charval = paste(charval, collapse=";")), id]
#   id      date1  charval
#1:  1 2009-01-02 aa;vv;ss
#2:  2 2009-01-05  a;b;c;d
```

---

As the OP's question is about `Map` with using `get` to call the `mean`.  This seems to be triggering the

> if (!is.numeric(x) && !is.complex(x) && !is.logical(x)) {
>           warning("argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA")
>           return(NA_real_)

and returns the NA when it finds that 'date1' is of class `Date` although it is stored as `numeric`.  One option is to specify the `envir` in `get`

Another problem is the use of `ifelse`.  It is better to use `if/else` as there are only two elements

```
dt2[, Map(function(x, y)  if(x != "paste") get(x, envir = parent.frame())(y, na.rm = TRUE) 
  else paste(y, collapse=':'), setNames(c("mean", "paste"), names(.SD)), .SD), by = id]
#    id      date1  charval
#1:  1 2009-01-02 aa:vv:ss
#2:  2 2009-01-05  a:b:c:d
```

`get` is kind of tricky and if specify the correct environment, it works as expected

```
get("mean")(dt2$date1)
#[1] "2009-01-04"
```

---

Or instead of `if/else` to the "paste" string, we can check on the column `class` and if it is `character` then do the `paste` or else return `mean`

```
dt2[, Map(function(x, y)  if(is.character(y)) get(x)(y, collapse=":") 
     else get(x, envir = parent.frame())(y, na.rm = TRUE),
     setNames(c("mean", "paste"), names(.SD)), .SD), by = id]
#   id      date1  charval
#1:  1 2009-01-02 aa:vv:ss
#2:  2 2009-01-05  a:b:c:d
```

Note that it is better to use the first approach without any hassles